# JWT Public Keys and Private Keys Invalid

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, public-key-encryption, private-key, public-key

I am trying to use JWT.io (https://jwt.io/#libraries) to create a JWT token.  However, when I add either my public key or private key for the signature portion, it keeps saying it is invalid.

I created the private and public key with the following respectively:

Generating a Private Key
 openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private_key.em 2048

Generating a Public Key
 openssl rsa -pubout -in private_key.pem -out public_key.em

Then all I do is copy-paste them into jwt.io.

All my other data is fine, it is just the public key and private key.

Answer (score 0):

JWT.io needs to use your private key to generated the signature for the JWT. However, your private key is encrypted with a password that JWT.io does not have because you used the `-aes256` flag with the `openssl genrsa` command. You should generate an unencrypted private key with the following command:

```
openssl genrsa -out private_key.em 2048
```

and paste that in to the JWT.io private key entry alongside of the public key.